# firebase web hosting but unexpected error (firebase init)

Tags: firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I don't know what is wrong.
[unexpected error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5EZW.png)
Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory.

I checked debug.log.
Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, scandir 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\수요일 특강\work1\index.html'
I ctrl+click the path, but it went to C:\Users\user\Desktop\수요일 특강\work1\index.html'
why they read '

Comment: Does the problem persist if you use a basic alphanumeric folder path? It may be that the tool you are using does not properly understand and/or expect multibyte characters but your operating system does.

Comment: can you check the error exist when using relative path ?